# What's the difference between OnStop() method and Stopping event in Windows Azure role?

Tags: windows, azure, cloud, azure-configuration

Whenever a Windows Azure role is stopped its `OnStop()` method is invoked. Turns out that there's [`RoleEnvironment.Stopping` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleenvironment.stopping.aspx) that is triggered before `OnStop()` is invoked. MSDN says this event is the right place for role clean shutdown code.

What's the difference between the two? Why would I put role clean shutdown code in `Stopping` event and not in `OnStop()` method override?

Answer (score 4):

Besides the fact that the event mechanism provides a flexible way to attach handlers, while the `OnStop` method has to be defined directly on the class derived from `RoleEntryPoint`, one relevant difference is this:

```
The Stopping event is not raised when the virtual machine of the role
instance is rebooted.
```

So the stopping event will not be raised, for instance, when the VM is rebooted for guest OS upgrade.

Another difference is this:

```
Code running in the OnStop method has 5 minutes to finish when it is called
for reasons other than a user-initiated shutdown.
```

While there is no mention in the documentation that the Stopping event has such a limit.

Source:

- [MSDN - RoleEnvironment.Stopping Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleenvironment.stopping.aspx)
- [MSDN - RoleEntryPoint.OnStop Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleentrypoint.onstop.aspx)

Comment: If you look into Azure processes logs you'll see that the 5 minutes limit is for the whole stopping sequence, so that's just MSDN being slightly wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Events allow other subscribers in other classes to perform some action, whereas the method allows the subclass author such as yourself to place it in the actual class and (for example) modify which events get raised.

Answer (score 1):

Brent Stineman (Windows Azure MVP) recently [blogged](http://brentdacodemonkey.wordpress.com/2011/09/24/leveraging-the-roleentrypoint-year-of-azure-week-12/) about the RoleEntryPoint and related start/run/stop sequence, and describes both Stopping and OnStop in the sequence descriptions.

Comment: Well, he says that the event is triggered before `OnStop()` is invoked. I don't see anything beyond that in that post.

Comment: As I understand it, and admittedly I haven't focused on testing this,  the Stopping is your first alert to clean up. So at this point you may stop taking on more work (pulling from a queue, shutting down your internal endpoint listener). Its also more of an async event. The OnStop is your final effort to get stopped and for which you only have 5 minutes to act on and its called directly by the Azure Fabric agent. This all does need more exploration but just simply hasn't been very high on my priority list. It could even be that these two items run in different security contexts.